# Facebook SQL WITH FQL

Tags: mysql, facebook-fql

say,i've sql and i get output in a while loop.

**UPDATED**
  **mysql code**
    While()
    {
     $a[] = row['a'];
    }
    $a;

**Note** Here $a is array.

Can,i pass this in fql SELECT query?

Comment: What does mysql have to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, but you can do something like:

```
$a = "";
while() {
    if ($a != "")
        $a .= row['a'];
    else
        $a .= "," . row['a'];
}
```

and pass that as a list in an IN clause.

Note that I have no idea what you want to do with it, and since your code looks like some kind of pseudo code, I've tried replying with the same syntax. I have no idea how you end that while loop or get anything but the same value from `$row['a']`.

Comment: :pass the mysql o/p array to facebook fql select query.

Comment: @user: But where does that array come from? Are you using php or something to fetch data from a MySQL database? Do you have the actual code you're using to build that array now?